# Material ui - unwanted margin around my headings and paragraphs

Tags: material-ui, css-grid, margin

I have an unwanted margin around my headings and paragraphs:

[image: Screenshot of unwanted margin]

I'm using `createMuiTheme` typography. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! It seems as though I should use  etc., instead...that appears to remove margins (gutters?)